# What database to store sensor data (JSON)

Tags: json, database, rdbms, nosql

I have a sensor network which today sends approx 20.000 JSON messages/day and right now I am sending them to a third party tool to analyze but to be better secured for future I would like to store these values in a database where I can have another UI tool for analysis.
I want to keep historical data for at least 2 years, probably more.
Access to the data has to be fast (e.g. selecting a sensor and values between two timestamps and to show in a graph)

So I wonder what kind of database I should go for; a normal SQL RDMS? (e.g. MySQL) or noSQL DB (no preference).
Can you give some guidance on database selection?

Sensors present themselves at startup with:

```
{
    "MonitoredSensors":
    [
        {"DeviceId":"12","Name":"Freezer","Service":"urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:EnergyMetering1","Variable":"Watts"},
        {"DeviceId":"14","Name":"Server","Service":"urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:EnergyMetering1","Variable":"Watts"},
        {"DeviceId":"103","Name":"EnergyMeter","Service":"urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:EnergyMetering1","Variable":"Watts"},
        {"DeviceId":"103","Name":"EnergyMeter","Service":"urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:EnergyMetering1","Variable":"KWH"},
        {"DeviceId":"89","Name":"TV","Service":"urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:EnergyMetering1","Variable":"Watts"},
        {"DeviceId":"101","Name":"Living Room Light","Service":"urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:LightSensor1","Variable":"CurrentLevel"}
    ],
    "Time":1411328122,
    "Version":"0.0.2"
}
```

Each sensor value reported by:

```
{
    "SensorValue":
    {
        "DeviceId":89,
        "NewValue":"161",
        "Time":1411596034,
        "Variable":"Watts",
        "Version":"0.0.2"
    }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: @4integrator You might want to know, that StackOverflow Netiquette discourages opinion based questions. You may even face some Moderator activity against such posts. In case you decide to re-edit and modify your question, there may be some quantitative goals added, so as the task gets measureable -- i.e. I want to get ad-hoc graphs to be processed under 500-750 msec over any depth of the historical timeseries. My current implementation is ...<_code-snippet_>... which produces graph in a not acceptable delay of 3 seconds. -- So make your best to show your already invested efforts and S/O helps

Comment: You should check out [Vertica](http://www.vertica.com/industries/sensor-analytics/). That's a relatively low number of messages though.

Answer (score 0):

Bascially any common RDBMS should be able to deal with it easily. If you have only few different analysis you want to perform, you can use Materialized Views to make it even faster.

If you don’t want to deserialize the JSON data and just throw raw JSON into the DataBase you could go with:

- MongoDB - which allows you easy, almost SQL-like, queries and will be fast once you have defined the proper indices
- CouchDB / CouchBase - which is similar to RDBMS’s Materialized Views, just with raw JSON. The disadvantage is that you won’t be able to run queries for which you havent created any view before hand.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @peter that probably any RDBMS can handle 20000*365*2 ~ 14.6 million records to do analysis on.

On top of that, you mentioned JSON records. I think the assumption here that the format of the JSON records might be different from different sensors or change over time.

For that "semi-structured" datasets have a look at

1. AVRO - https://avro.apache.org/
2. Parquet - https://parquet.apache.org/

formats that can embed JSON-like formats and support [Schema Evolution](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/05/three-reasons-why-apache-avro-data-serialization-is-a-good-choice-for-openrtb/).

Althoug AVRO and Parquet are not databases, but there are many "databases" that work natively with both AVRO and Parquet among other dataformats:

- Spark
- Hive
- Impala

to name a few. All three of the above are also very scalable, in case if later you decide to stream not 20k but 20m messages a day for example.